# Rebase a branch checked out from another branch onto master without dragging first branches' commits

Tags: git, rebase

I'm wrestling with a particular situation I have with git.

In short I am trying to rebase a branch (`feature/tracking-refactor`) which was checked out from another branch (`feature/basic-tracking`) which was checked out from `origin/master`.

After merging `feature/basic-training` I would like to rebase `feature/tracking-refactor` onto master without dragging `feature/basic-training` commits onto the new `origin/master`.

Below a more graphical representation of my situation. Say that I have a git log graph such as the following as the starting point.

[image: Previous git log]

And, after a successfull pull request having merged `feature/basic-tracking` onto master, I am currently at this situation.

[image: Current git log]

But, when I try to rebase `feature/tracking-refactor` onto master in order to have a clean-like log history, I am actually dragging every commit also from `feature/basic-tracking` as well. I would like to just rebase `feature/tracking-refactor` commits such as those with (d0875g and ee68b9t) SHA alone.

My work around this would be to create a new branch from `origin/master` and to cherry pick each commit from `feature/tracking-refactor` branch. But I was hoping for a more elegant alternative. Thanks!

Comment: search for `rebase --onto`.

Comment: Would you give an example with my current situation here as to how it would work?

Comment: I don't have time to write it up properly, but essentially, `git rebase --onto` lets you split out the target and the cutoff. Here the target is `origin/master` and the cutoff is commit `c15t43f` (though `t` is not a valid character in a commit hash ID!).

Comment: @torek I wrote it by hand, don't expect it to be flawless...

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase --onto`. It can be thought of this way: `git rebase --onto target-branch discard-branch branch-to-rebase`. So, *discard-branch* will tell rebase the revisions that *won't* be carried out on the rebase operation. In your case it would be (if I understtod correctly):

```
git rebase --onto origin/master feature/basic-training feature/tracking-refactor
```

Actually, **if feature/basic-training has already been merged into origin/master**, you could do:

```
git checkout feature/tracking-refactor
git rebase origin/master
```

Or

```
git rebase --onto origin/master origin/master feature/tracking-refactor
```

Hope it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. I still see all the commits already merged into master with a previous branch.